# Stop html from being rendered inside code blocks

Tags: html, css, node.js, ghost-blog

My problem is that HTML is being rendered inside code tags.
In ghost blog I have had no issues using code tags.
Except from HTML, which is actually rendered.

This example from below is actually *rendered*.

```
<pre><code>
<div>some text</div>
<input value="even this is rendered"></input>
</code></pre>
```

If I use 4-spaces inline it works fine.
I'm using the default style layout.

Looking at the official markdown-documentation this is supposed to work.
http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<code>` isn't supposed to stop HTML being rendered. It means "Present this in a way that indicates it is code" not "Don't treat this HTML as HTML".

Use character references for characters with special meaning in HTML if you want them to be displayed (`&amp;`, `&lt;`, etc).

The Markdown documentation says:

> Within a code block, ampersands (&) and angle brackets (< and >) are automatically converted into HTML entities.

… but *code block* means "When the markdown source is indented by 4 characters" not "When wrapped in pre/code".

Comment: Alright, I understand. Escaping or placing inline is a tiny bit more hassle than I'd hoped for (don't shoot me!). Do you know why there's no "escape-html" tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping problematic characters:

```
<pre><code>    
&lt;div&gt;some text&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;input value=&quot;even this is rendered&quot;&gt;&lt;/input&gt;
</code></pre>
```